# Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.(Cause firebase new update)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hey guys after the firebase new update 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
i started getting this error but then i relaeiesd the cause of it.
it happens after clicking send the verification code, the error looked like
this:

> E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17042 Invalid format.

the problem was because i didn't put the SHA-1 and SHA-256 so i put them, then i tried to start the program again but it didn't work and i still get the same errors this one

> E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17042 Invalid format.

and after the previous error i get this error

> Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I feel dump, anyways for the people who got the same problem please check if you put the country code before the `phonenumber` variable.

Comment: tthhhaaannnkkksss

Comment: For me, for some weird reason, it wasn't working if I was adding the country code without any spacing between it and the rest of the phone number. But only worked if I added a space. For example: +15558873784 didn't work but +1 5558873784 worked

Answer (score 3):

first of all be sure you are adding SHA1 SHA256 keys in your firebase project in the setting fingerprint..

if above get failed ..

you need to put country code (eg.+91 1234567890)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone number must replace like below:

*textPhone = textPhone.toString().replaceFirst('0', '**countryCode**');*

countryCode like +84: Viet Nam...

Good look!

Answer (score -1):

Check if you pass the  data or not of phone number in verifyPhoneNo activity or something else you have.
Otherwise you missed put the country code.